# How do I write a code that uses the accumulation pattern to take the sum of all of the numbers and assigns it to an int?

Tags: python, iteration

addition_str is a string and I need to convert the values in it to int using accumulation but we haven't covered this in the text.

I don't know how to solve this. I've tried numerous combinations of for loops but my code is still wrong. I know what I have below is useless but I do not have a record of all the combinations I've used so far.

```
addition_str = "2+5+10+20"
print(addition_str.split("+"))

print (int("2"))
print (int("5"))
print (int("10"))
print (int("20"))

accum = 0
for i in num_chars:
    accum = accum + i
print(accum)
```

addition_str is a string with a list of numbers separated by the + sign. Write code that uses the accumulation pattern to take the sum of all of the numbers and assigns it to sum_val (an integer). (You should use the .split("+") function to split by "+" and int() to cast to an integer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution step by step:

1. `addition_str.split("+")` will return `['2','5','10','20']`
2. `map(int,addition_str.split("+"))` will return a `map` object
3. `sum(map(int,['2','5','10','20']))` will return 37

So with one-line style it gives the following:

```
sum_val = sum(map(int,addition_str.split("+")))
```

Comment: On Python 3, `map(int,['2','5','10','20'])` is a generator, not a list…

Comment: Hey you're right sir ! I have updated my post. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE to be very pedantic, it is neither a generator nor a list, it is a map-object, which is an iterator.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate the step by step explanation.

Comment: It's right, but this doesn't explain the accumulation pattern…

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
accumulation = []
mylist = []

addition_str = "2+5+10+20"
str_nums = (addition_str.split("+"))
for i in str_nums:
    mylist.append(int(i))
    accumulation.append(sum(mylist))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I can explain this to you:

First, once your *addition_str* is split, you get a list of strings. You need to turn them into integer to calculate the sum.

One efficient way to do that is to use a comprehension list:

```py
values = [int(s) for s in strings]
```

But, you can also use a classic loop:

```py
values = []
for s in strings:
    values.append(int(s))
```

Here, *values* is a list of integers, for instance: `[2, 5, 10, 20]` (without quotation).

To accumulate, you need an initial value (zero) then iterate the loop and add each value to your accumulator:

```py
acc = 0
for value in values:
    acc += value
```

Try that and tell me if you don't get the right sum.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to solve the problem:

```py
addition_str = "2+5+10+20"
su = addition_str.split('+')

sum_val = 0
for i in su:
    sum_val = sum_val + int(i)

print(sum_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension is a good way to go:

```
total = sum([int(i) for i in original_string.split('+')])
```

In a for loop you have,

```
accumulator = 0
for i in original_string.split('+'):
    accumulator += int(i)

total = accumulator
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addition_str = "2+5+10+20"

sum_val=0
for a in addition_str:
    a.split(addition_str)
    sum_val = sum(map(int,addition_str.split("+")))
print(sum_val)
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Answer (score 0):

This is a task coming from the coursera Python 3 Programming by Univ of Michigan. In line what has been thought in the study materials

```
addition_str = "2+5+10+20"

addition_str = addition_str.split('+')

sum_val = 0
for n in addition_str:
sum_val = sum_val + int(n)

print(sum_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that by this way, trying to convert iterable variables.
string to list - list(consisting from strings)- (to list consisting from integers). It works

```
addition_str = "2+5+10+20"
addition_num = addition_str.split("+")
addition_int = list(addition_num)
sum_val = 0
    for num in addition_int:
    number = int(num)
    sum_val += number
    print(sum_val)
```

Comment: addition_str = "2+5+10+20"
addition_num = addition_str.split("+")
addition_int = list(addition_num)
sum_val = 0
for num in addition_int:
    number = int(num)
    sum_val += number
    print(sum_val)